# Content and footer space problems

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

I don't know why the space between the content-bottom and the footer is bigger than the space between  header and content-top you can see an example here: [not found]. I want the same equal spacing for the content(that box) between header and footer...but always I get bigger spacing between content and footer..and I don't know how to fix it, please help me guys.

Best Regards

Comment: Can we see some code? Preferably the relevant markup (HTML) and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given your header, position:absolute and footer position:fixed. also height to middle container. This way your elements won't flow correctly.

My suggestion:

give header and footer position normal.
and give content:

.wrap {margin:100px auto; width:---px;}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.css('height')`, use `.height()` or `.outerHeight()` if you want to calculate also padding and margins of the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Firebug plugin (http://getfirebug.com/) if you have Firefox. Using this plugin, you can view the CSS of individual elements on the page by hovering over them and pressing ctrl+shift+c.

You may also view paddings, margins, and heights via the "Layout" tab as well as edit CSS and see updates immediately as live, local changes. That allows for rapid CSS debugging.